# Xcode 7 IPA same size, doubled size on store (TestFlight)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios9, xcode7, bitcode, app-thinning

We have rebuilt our Unity Project with Xcode 7. The weird thing is that, once submitted to the App Store and checked with TestFlight, my build jumped from 98 MB to 215 MB (it lowers to about 180 MB when downloaded from iOS 8 instead of iOS 9). The created .IPA file has exactly the same dimension, it's just something that happens during the submission to the store (I guess that it has something to do with bitcode (actually disabled) and application thinning).

Is there a way to submit with Xcode 7 without those problems? We are still not ready to use application thinning, because we are working with Unity, but would like to use Xcode 7 to test on iOS 9 devices.

Comment: We have a similar problem too. After disabling Bitcode and excluding symbols; size reduced in ITunnes Connect web page but TestFlight still shows 170MB (which was about 70mb before). We are not sure if should we go to prod or not.

Comment: Have you solved the issue ? We are stuck with xcode 6.5 still

Comment: seems to be fixed with XCode 7.1.0 beta 2 , don't know if even 7.0.1 fixes that.